# How to change gnome shell theme with a bash script?

Tags: shell-script, gnome-shell, theme

I wanted to created a script which automatically changes light and dark theme at a certain time. I managed to change the gtk-theme but couldn't find a way to change the shell theme. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update:
So, I tried using the following code but it still won't work.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "Vimix-Light"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the reason why the above code didn't work was because a file named **"org.gnome.extensions.user-theme.gschema.xml"** was missing from **"/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/"**.

To solve the problem run the following code :

```
sudo cp $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```